# NetBeans Android SDK Plugin Activation Error

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I am trying to download the Android SDK on NetBeans 7.4 on a Mac via the NB Android plugin. After I installation is completed, NetBeans warns me that several modules needed were not read and could not be installed, so when I try to activate the plugin to import the SDK, it gives me an error: Activation Failed: Not all requested modules could be enabled.

Could somebody please help me with this tell me what is wrong? The three links below (especially the last one) will help you guys for further reference of the problem Thank you very much.

https://netbeans.org/index.html

http://nbandroid.org/wiki/index.php/Installation#How_to_install

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200215

Answer (score 0):

The information you have provided is incomplete. Which modules? Bug report can be a similar problem or not. It is possible that your installation is broken - try to delete NBAndroid modules and download/install them again. Or do similar thing with NetBeans.